# react with lumen authentication logic

Tags: php, node.js, reactjs, authentication, redux

i am making a web app use with react 4 and lumen to backend api. i made a login form use on username and password but i don't know how can i logged the user and kick out from the pacge if the user is not logged in.

I looked for many login example for the react but almost all of it use redux and i a newbie on this so it is very complex for me.

I want to learn this logic that means how can i use and why ? how it can be stored secure? how can protect to user like php session in react. how can i use auth middleware like in laravel.

could i use session in react ? is it possible?

no one make an app about i told. i don't want to use express and nodejs. i am using php server on backend ?

please help me

Comment: i told it give me an answer instead of edit my text who wants to edit this text. you are only pathetic. what did you handle change "could" to "Could". brat ...

Comment: You are asking too many questions. And calling people trying to improve your original post pathetic is not going to help you.

Comment: too many question ? all of it belongs to one main question that is the how can i use middleware on authentication. i did nothing if you don't understand main goal.

Answer (score 1):

React will be a different server same like php server, you will communicate through **REST API** Rest is stateless protocol so you cant use php session inside react application, recommended way to solve this issue is introduce JWT in backend Use [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) this reference for that.